# Exercise 2.20 from “Mathematical Statistics - Jun Shao”

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

> Let ${ \left\{ X_{ i } \right\}  }_{ i=1 }^{ n } \sim E(a,\theta)$
>   where $a \in {\rm I\!R}$, and $\theta > 0$. Show that the smallest
>   order statistic, $X_{(1)}$, has the exponential distribution
>   $E(a,\theta/n)$ and that $2\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ (X_{ i }-X_{ (1) }) }
>  /\theta \sim { \chi  }_{ 2n-2 }^{ 2 }$.

I have shown that the smallest order statistic $X_{(1)} \sim E(a,\theta/n)$. But I'm struggling in the second part. I think I can use the Basu Theorem, but I believe that there are other simpler option. Any hint?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764443/for-a-random-sample-from-the-distribution-fx-e-x-theta-x-theta-sh/.