# Show that the random variable has Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\cdots ,X_n$ are iid. random variables and have pdf $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma } e^{- \frac{x - \mu }{\sigma } } I(x \geq \mu) $$
Find out the distribution of $$Y := \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{min} ) $$
where $X_{min}$ stands for the $\min \{X_1, \cdots , X_n \}$.

The book tells me that $Y$ has certain gamma distribution. My idea is to show that $X_i - X_{min}$ are independent random variables, so that since they have the exponential distribution, there sum has gamma distribution. However, I am not able to prove the independence. Can anyone offer a solution, or they are in fact not independent ?

Comment: Consider the case when $n=1$. Then the only $X_i$ is $X_n=X_{\mathrm{min}}$, at which point they're *definitely* not independent. I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem, but one vague approach might be to start by characterising $X_\mathrm{min}$ using the the method of order statistics, and then maybe you could calculate the moment generating function of the sum (using the property that the moment generating function of a sum is the product of the individual moment generating functions) and see if you could manipulate that into the form of the mgf of the gamma distribution or something

Comment: $X_i - X_{\min}$ is $0$ for exactly one $i$ with probability $1$, and for any particular $i$ you have $\mathbb P(X_i - X_{\min}=0) = \frac1n$. So they are not independent .  But if it is $i=1$ for which this is zero, then I think you can use memorylessness to show the other $X_i - X_{\min}$ are independent

Comment: I also thought of the memoryless property but I didn't know how to make use of it.

Comment: You can use a specific change of variables to show this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764443/for-a-random-sample-from-the-distribution-fx-e-x-theta-x-theta-sh/).